# Where do Rails Jobs get called from in ActionCable and how can you pass parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, jobs, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

For example where is the the `perform` method originally getting called in this following job in:

jobs/message_broadcast_job.rb

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel", message: render_message(message) #, roomId: roomId
  end

  private
    def render_message(message)
      ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: { message: message })
    end
end
```

In assets/javascripts/channels/room.coffee there is a method call:

```
  speak: (message, roomId) ->
    @perform 'speak', message: message, roomId: roomId
```

But that seems to call the corresponding method in channels/room_channel.rb:

```
def speak(data)
     Message.create! text: data['message'], user_id: 1, room_id: data['roomId']
  end
```

So where is the job getting called from, and how can I pass parameters into it? (Specifically I have a room channel ID I've already passed to `room_channel.rb` via parameters, but also need to get this in the perform action to broadcast from the relevant room channel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the model, `models/message.rb`

```
after_create_commit { MessageBroadcastJob.perform_later self }
```

Puts the job into the queue after the creation of the message. Therefore, in the job file you can access parameters via the object itself, in this case the message.

Specifically, in this case it would be:

```
 def perform(message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel_#{message.room_id}", message: render_message(message) #, roomId: roomId
  end
```

As all of the attributes for message are available.